# How to disable download button in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, integration-testing, developer-tools

How to disable download button in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio ?
In output Audio plugin UI there is three vertically dot that is download option. I want to hide this..

```
<figure>
    <figcaption>Listen to the T-Rex:</figcaption>
    <audio
        controls
        src="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3">
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
</figure>
```

I tried also this npm package [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-player)

Comment: I'm not sure if this an official attribute, but you can try adding `controlsList="nodownload"` to the `<audio>` element. `controlsList="nodownload"` is usually used with the `<video>` element